# casting problem from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Suppose i have this sql statement and I have executed a sql command to get a datareader:

```
"select 1 union select 2"
//.....
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and now i want to read the value in the first column of the first row:

```
var myInt = (int)rdr.GetValue(0); //great this works
var myLong = (long)rdr.GetValue(0); //throws cast exception, even though you can cast int to long
```

So it appears the type you cast to in C# needs to match exactly the SQL type.  I.E. If the sql type is bigint, you can only cast to long. If the sql type is int, you can only cast to int. No mix and match...

I just want to get something that works regardless of the type of integer c# asks for and sql returns, as long as you could theoretically cast one to the other.  So if SQL Server gives me a floating point type, and I'm asking for an int, I want the truncated int you get from doing that cast.

My goal is to make this work with generics, so I can have this function work when the generic parameter doesn't exactly match the datatype in sql server:

```
List<T> GetFirstColumn<T>(string sql) where T : struct
{
    //get connection, execute reader
    // loop: 
    //    lst.Add(  (T) rdr.GetValue(0));
}
```

I'd like this to work for both statments:

```
var sql1 = "Select 1"; //sql int
var sql2 = "Select cast(1 as bigint)"; //sql equivalent of a long
var lst1 = GetFirstColumn<int>(sql1);
var lst2 = GetFirstColumn<int>(sql2);
```

Does anyone have a relatively painless way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Convert will take care of the conversion.

```
T GetValue<T>(SqlDataReader rdr)
{
    var dbVal = rdr.GetValue(0);
    var csVal = (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(dbVal, typeof(T));
}
```

Caveat: if `T == Nullable<S>`, you need to do some extra work with reflection to get the underlying type and call ChangeType with `typeof(S)` as the type parameter.  Apparently, MS didn't update the ChangeType function with .NET 2.0 and the introduction of nullables.  And if it's a nullable, and `dbVal is DBNull`, you can just return null.

```
object dbValue = 5;

//this throws
Convert.ChangeType(dbValue, typeof(int?));

//this works
if(dbValue == DBNull.Value || dbValue == null) 
{
  if(typeof(int?).IsNullable) //or is a class, like string
  {return null;}

  dbValue = null;
}

var type = GetUnderlyingType<int?>(); //== typeof(int)
Convert.ChangeType(dbValue, type);
```

Answer (score 5):

Like Fredrik says, the value from SqlDataReader is boxed. You can convert a boxed value to an `int` with `Convert.ToInt32`, like:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(read[0]);
```

This will try to convert even if SQL Server returns a bigint or a decimal.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that `GetValue` returns an `object`. This means that in the case of an `int`, you will get an `int` boxed in an `object`. Then you cannot directly cast it to a `long` but must first unpack it as an `int`:

```
var myLong = (long)(int)rdr.GetValue(0);
```

This will be quite tricky using generics, I would say. Well, you *could* make generic methods with two type arguments; one specifying what type the field is, and one specifying the type you want. But I don't really see the need; `SqlDataReader` already has methods for the various data types, such as `GetInt32`, `GetInt64` and so on, so the generic method would not really give any added value in that case.

Comment: the point is to be able to call it from C# without caring what the sql server type is, as long as it is convertible